# Java Binary Search Tree implementation problem.!

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree

I am developing a binary search tree in java. But i am facing certain difficulties in it. Here is the code

```
class Node {

    Node left, right;
    Integer data;

    Node(Integer d, Node left, Node right) {
        this.data = d;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
}

class BinaryTree {

    Node root;

    public BinaryTree(Node root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

    void insert(int d)
    {
        if(root==null)
            root= new Node(d, null, null);
        insert(root,d);
    }
    void insert(Node root, int d) {
        if (root == null) {
            root=new Node(d,null,null);
        } else if (d > root.data) {
            insert(root.right, d);
        } else if (d < root.data) {
            insert(root.left, d);
        }
    }

    void inorder(Node root) {
        if (root != null) {
            inorder(root.left);
            System.out.println(root.data);
            inorder(root.right);
        }
    }
}

public class BST {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String str = null;
        BinaryTree bt=new BinaryTree(null);
        while (!(str = br.readLine()).equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
            bt.insert(Integer.parseInt(str));
        }
        bt.inorder(bt.root);
    }
}
```

The problem here i am facing is as in java there is only pass by value. I am getting the root as null in every case except the first case in which i have passed the newly created root into it. Here when i am making a recursive call to the insert function by passing the value of either left or right of the root then in the new call the new root has been created if required for it but when the function gets over it's values are not reflected to the caller function's variable. 
In short the problem is due to the call by value being followed by the java.

Can anyone please suggest the solution for this problem?

Comment: Your problem lies in that you're trying to "change" a `null` value

Comment: Also are you aware that your first insert method is trying to insert d twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your calls to `insert(root.right/left, d)` do not change the original right/left nodes if they are null, but simply make the *method arguments* point to a new variable (which, as you noticed, in Java won't change the original reference). Your change to the first root works because you call a different method, `insert(int)`.

Have you considered making left and right `BinaryTree`s instead of `Node`s? Also, instead of using "null", consider having an "empty" BinaryTree (with a null root and an `isEmpty` method).

Note that *conceptually*, left and right are trees, not nodes, so the design will be cleaner.

---

**Example code. Untested but the idea should be right:**

```
class Node {

    BinaryTree left, right;
    Integer data;

    Node(Integer d, BinaryTree left, BinaryTree right) {
        this.data  = d;
        this.left  = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
} 

class BinaryTree {

    Node root;

    // Empty tree
    BinaryTree() {
        this(null);
    }

    BinaryTree(Node root) {
        this.root == root;
    }

    void insert(int d) {

        if (this.root == null) {

            // The tree was empty, so it creates a new root with empty subtrees
            this.root = new Node(d, new BinaryTree(), new BinaryTree());

        } else if (d > this.root.data) {
            this.root.right.insert(d);
        } else if (d < this.root.data) {
            this.root.left.insert(d);
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

- I respected the style of your existing code.
- This implementation will skip repeated elements.

Comment: I have to make the program as optimum as possible. And can you please give some code sample of the solution that you are suggesting? Because the problem i am facing is call by value which is not reflecting any values in my function when recursive call completes.

Comment: @ankur.trapasiya I've added an example. Might have errors since I haven't tried it, but should work.

Comment: yes it will work. I have to modity root==null condition however but it is ok... Thanks..:-)

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions,

- I wouldn't use an `Integer` if you mean to use an `int` value.
- If you are reproducing code which is in the JVM already, I would read how the code works there first (and copy what you need)
- When I have a bug in my code, I use the debugger to work out what is going wrong.
- I start with a the simplest unit I can make which shows the problem, and fixes that simple situation.

I would post the simplest unit test, which anyone can reproduce, and what you see in the debugger here if it doesn't make any sense.

This doesn't really answer your question, but is too long for a comment. ;)

Comment: Actually i have made this program in c++ but i am more comfortable with java. Now java doesn't have any pointer like structure so what i have to do in order to make the binary tree because each time when recursive call ends the values are not reflected with the new values. I have debugged and by debugging only i came to the reason why it is not happening. I am just asking is there any way in java to do this ?? I am not asking for the code. Just hints will be more than enough.

Comment: The code is in the TreeMap class, so you can do it and I don't need to give it to you.

Comment: Yes, I tried it. It is also working but i am trying to develop a program for binary search tree. Thanks :-)...!!!!!